# Our heart or our hearts

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I just read a quote in which someone, on behalf of herself and her spouse, wrote "**Our heart goes out for ....**". I Googled to know if when it comes to speaking about heart not as a body organ, is it possible to use it in the singular form, but I could not find any reliable source for that.

So, what is the correct form for such situations and does it apply for other organs, specifically brain?

Comment: Probably they meant their “heart” as a couple.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [Head or heads?](/questions/113558)

Comment: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=our+heart+goes+out+to%2Cour+hearts+go+out+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) show that both 'our heart goes out to' and 'our hearts go out to' are used, the latter being much the more common, emphasising the level of concern rather than the unity of those concerned. But with metaphorical usages especially, the distributive singular is common. 'The boys   wanted to get something off their chest but had a change of heart.'

Comment: May this be related to the accent, because the writer was an American?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thanks, but that is not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: The answer is that the distributive plural is grammatically acceptable here (as indicated in the previous thread); research shows that the plural is also available and more common _in this particular case_. This is not always the case: 'The visitors wanted to get something off their chest but had a change of heart'

Comment: The heart here is no bodily organ but the figurative seat of emotion. Your question must be can a couple have one heart?

Comment: RELATED: [When to use "lives" as a plural of life?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77176/when-to-use-lives-as-a-plural-of-life) and [Is it proper to say, "our mind" or "our minds" as each person has one mind; or is it considered collectively?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516701/)